# how to change format of date from mm/dd/yyyy to dd-mmm-yyyy in MS Excel

Tags: excel

I need to upload data onto a software from my excel sheet. however the format of is not changing from mm/dd/year (e.g 08/28/18) to dd-mmm-year (e.g 28-Aug-2018 or 28-Aug-18)

please assist.

Comment: Is the destination software looking for a specific date formatted string or an actual date?  If it's looking for a string, then you should use the formula =TEXT(A1,"dd-mm-yyyy") to convert it to a properly formatted string.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Take a look at this screenshot]

Select the cell(s) you need to format.
- Then click on the small pop out icon in the Number section (circled in the image)
- This will open up the dialog box as shown
- Click on Custom
- In the Type: select from one of the standard ones or create your own. (Use the sample above to see if it is as per requirement)

Comment: If the data coming in is different than the local settings it will come in as text and no matter what format is used it will not change.

Answer (score 0):

```
mm/dd/yyyy is the default format in MS Excel. You have to create a custom date format 
for your requirement as it does not exist in excel by default. 
First select your cells containing dates and right click of mouse and select Format Cells. 
In Number Tab, select Custom then type 'dd-mmm-yyyy' in Type text box, then click okay. 
It will format your selected dates.
```

Comment: No, `mm/dd/yyyy` is not the default in Excel, VBA yes, worksheet no.  The default is set by the local settings of the computer.  It could be `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`  If the data coming in is different than the local settings it will come in as text and no matter what format is used it will not change.

Answer (score 0):

Imported date-data formatted different from your computer's local setting will be stored as text string. Select the data, one column at at time. Select `> Data > Text to Columns`, select `Delimited > Next`, select `Tab > Next`, select `Date` and choose from the pull-down menu the format in which the data is present in the text (e.g. `DMY` or `MDY` etc.). This will convert the text string into the equivalent Excel date string, after which you can assign it any date format you want.